# How do I assign a value to the <select> <option>s to display a certain image named after the val?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently working on a Configurator for which I've had to create a serial number based on values to display a certain image. I'm having trouble hiding some select options as I'm not sure how to do this based on the tags value / image name.

I've got to the point where I figured out how to hide/show the options, but I'm not sure how to assign values to the options now...

The Size Values can be translated as is, but the Type (Stahl, Poly, etc.) should be translated as letters (F, B, A, etc...)

```js
let Laenge = 0;
let Teller = 0;
let KappeFarbe = 1;
let Teller2 = 0;
let GA = 0;
let GD = 0;
let VO = 0;
let VU = 0;

function dropdownTeller(element) {
  Teller = element.value;
  if (GA != 0 && GD != 0) {
    if (KappeFarbe = 1) {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + GA + GD + VO + VU + ".png)";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + KappeFarbe + GA + GD + VO + VU + ".png)";
    }
  } else {
    if (KappeFarbe = 1) {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + ".png)";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + KappeFarbe + ".png)";
    }
  }
}

function dropdownTeller2(element) {
  Teller2 = element.value;
  document.getElementById("durchmesser").style.visibility = "visible"
  if (GA != 0 && GD != 0) {
    if (KappeFarbe = 1) {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + GA + GD + VO + VU + ".png)";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + KappeFarbe + GA + GD + VO + VU + ".png)";
    }
  } else {
    if (KappeFarbe = 1) {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + ".png)";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + KappeFarbe + ".png)";
    }
    const FVal = new Array("19", "20", "30");
  }
}

/* jQuery TEST */
var subjectObject = {
  "Stahlteller": [
    "19",
    "20",
    "30",
    "33",
    "35",
    "40",
    "45",
    "50",
    "60"
  ],
  "Stahlteller abgeschnitten": [
    "40/35",
    "40/30"
  ],
  "Stahlteller abgeschnitten mit 2 Anschraublöchern": [
    "40/35",
    "40/30"
  ],
  "Stahlteller mit 2 Anschraublöchern": [
    "30",
    "40",
    "45",
    "50",
    "60"
  ],
  "Stahlteller mit 3 Anschraublöchern": [
    "45"
  ],
  "Stahlteller mit 4 Anschraublöchern": [
    "80"
  ],
  "Stahlteller gewölbt": [
    "40"
  ],
  "Edelstahlteller": [
    "25",
    "30",
    "36",
    "40",
    "50",
    "60",
    "70",
    "75"
  ],
  "Edelstahlgelenkteller": [
    "60",
    "70"
  ],
  "Edelstahlteller STABIL": [
    "50"
  ],
  "Polyamidteller": [
    "20",
    "30",
    "36",
    "48",
    "50"
  ]
}

window.onload = function() {
  var subjectSel = document.getElementById("teller2");
  var topicSel = document.getElementById("teller");

  for (var x in subjectObject) {
    subjectSel.appendChild(new Option(x, x));
  }
  subjectSel.onchange = function() { //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns

    //subjectSel.length = 1;   
    topicSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
      topicSel.appendChild(new Option(subjectObject[this.value][y], y));
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.buttonrow {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.rightoption {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonrow">
  <div class="Gewinde">
    <h4> Fußteller Art: </h4>
    <select name="teller2" id="teller2" onchange="dropdownTeller2(this)">
      <option value="0"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttonrow" id="durchmesser">
  <div class="Gewinde">
    <h4> Fußteller Größe: </h4>
    <select name="teller" id="teller" onchange="dropdownTeller(this)">
      <option value="0">Durchmesser (mm)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see one issue - `=` needs to be `==` in your `if` conditions, but it's not clear from your question what the exact issue or goal is. The code seems to work fine

Comment: On the full site there is a div that displays an image according to the value of the options. The value for the mm option should be the size (for example 19), and a Letter for the Material (F for Steel, for example), so the code can reach the sizes image in the img folder. For Example, the simple solution for the other select attributes is: GA = element.value;
 
 if ( Teller > 0 && KappeFarbe != 1 ) {
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage= "url(konfig/" + Teller2 + Teller + KappeFarbe + GA + GD + VO + VU + ".png)";
 
 }

Comment: Where are those values set? In your example code, `GA`, `GD`, `VO`, `VU`, `KappeFarbe` etc are never updated?

Comment: Values are updated when the selectors option is changed. I kinda expressed it weirdly, but each of them have their own selector function. They don't influence eachother (other than the values) so it was easy to handle for me. The default value for them is 0 and defined at the start of the doc with let GA = 0, etc. Every option has a different value, which is why Ga, etc. are then assigned element.value under change of their respective selector

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is I'm looking for a way to assign the numbers in the Javascript each an individual value, as well as the"Stahlteller"s

Answer (score 0):

Alright. With countless headaches, I've finally found a working solution. As the second selector isn't visible until the first one is changed (I didnt post the full code because I thought that wouldn't help... guess I thought wrong) I just discarded my jQuery section and came up with this instead:

```
    <div class="Gewinde">
    
        <h4> Fußteller Art: </h4>
        
        <select name="teller2" id="teller2" onchange="dropdownTeller2(this)">
        
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="F">Stahlteller</option>
            <option value="A">Stahlteller abgeschnitten</option>
            <option value="N">Stahlteller abgeschnitten mit 2 Anschraublöchern</option>
            <option value="L">Stahlteller mit 2 Anschraublöchern</option>
            <option value="B">Stahlteller mit 3 Anschraublöchern</option>
            <option value="C">Stahlteller mit 4 Anschraublöchern</option>
            <option value="G">Stahlteller gewölbt</option>  
            <option value="T">Stahlteller sechskant</option>    
            <option value="E">Edelstahlteller</option>
            <option value="D">Edelstahlgelenkteller</option>
            <option value="STABIL">Edelstahlteller STABIL</option>
            <option value="K">Polyamidtellerteller</option>
            
        </select>
    
    </div>

    <div class="Gewinde">
    
        <h4> Fußteller Größe: </h4>
        
        <select name="teller" id="teller" onchange="dropdownTeller(this)">
         
            <option value="0">Durchmesser</option>
        </select>
                    
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('teller2').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var teller = document.getElementById('teller');
    var teller2Value = this.value;

    // Clear all options
    teller.innerHTML = '';

    if (teller2Value === 'A' || teller2Value === 'N') {
        teller.add(new Option('Durchmesser', '0'));
        teller.add(new Option('40/35', '1'));
        teller.add(new Option('40/30', '2'));
    } else if (teller2Value === 'C') {
        teller.add(new Option('Durchmesser', '0'));
        teller.add(new Option('80', '80'));
    } else if (teller2Value === 'F') {
        teller.add(new Option('Durchmesser', '0'));
        teller.add(new Option('19', '19'));
        teller.add(new Option('20', '20'));
        teller.add(new Option('30', '30'));
        teller.add(new Option('33', '33'));
        teller.add(new Option('35', '35'));
        teller.add(new Option('40', '40'));
        teller.add(new Option('45', '45'));
        teller.add(new Option('50', '50'));
        teller.add(new Option('60', '60'));
        
    }
});
```

It works flawlessly (for now, atleast). The images are displayed as they should be onchange.